# Im been trying to solve this but nothings popping out

Tags: sequences-and-series

Three numbers form a geometric sequence. If 5 is added to the second term, then the resulting numbers will constitute an arithmetic sequence. If 22.5 is added to the third number, these numbers will again form a geometric sequence. Find the original numbers.

Comment: So you have three numbers $a,b,c$ and three relations derived from the given conditions to solve for them. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Change the title and make reference to your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Three numbers are in geometric progression, so we can call them $a, ar, ar^2$.

Adding 5 to the middle one puts them in arithmetic progression, so:

$$ar^2-(ar+5) = ar +5-a$$

Adding $22.5$ to the third numbers puts them back in geometric progression, so:

$$\frac{ar^2+22.5}{ar +5} = \frac{ar +5}{a}$$

or:

$$a(ar^2+22.5) = (ar +5)^2$$

That's a system of two polynomial equations in two unknowns. You can solve the top one for $a$:

$$a= \frac{10}{r^2-2r+1}$$

If you plug that into the second equation, you'll have an equation in just $r$. Does that help?

Comment: Good job Tony you beat me to it, good explanation too =)